# Search map marker using places autocomplete Google maps

Tags: java, android, routes, google-api, geolocation

I have markers for terminals and I want to search it using the places autocomplete, tried different methods but still cant figure it out, do I need geolocation for it? or I can use other methods for this? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have. Thank you in advance for your help!

Codes for autocomplete

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        String apiKey = getString(R.string.places_api_key);

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
        }

        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);



        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setLocationBias(RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                new LatLng(15.147181, 120.584733),
                new LatLng(15.147181, 120.584733)
        ));

        //Select Country

        autocompleteFragment.setCountries("PH");

        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());

                // Get the LatLng of the selected place
                LatLng selectedPlaceLatLng = place.getLatLng();

                // Define a new CameraPosition with desired zoom level
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(selectedPlaceLatLng) // Sets the center of the map to the selected place's LatLng
                        .zoom(15) // Desired zoom level
                        .build();

                // Move the camera to the new position
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }


            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
```

Codes on my markers

```
 // Add some markers to the map, and add a data object to each marker.
        markerMarisolTerm = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MarisolTerminal)
                .title("Marisol Terminal")
                 .flat(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marisol)));
        markerMarisolTerm.setTag(0);

        markerVillaTerminal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(VillaTerminal)
                .title("Villa Terminal")
                 .flat(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.villa)));
        markerVillaTerminal.setTag(0);

        markerCheckpointTerminal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CheckpointTerminal)
                .title("Checkpoint Terminal")
                .flat(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.checkpoint)));
        markerCheckpointTerminal.setTag(0);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I want to search it" - I can only guess a) you want to create a rectangular bounds using your map marker positions or b) you want to find the nearest marker to the selected place or something else entirely?  And why is your bias a single point?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question,  I have a autocomplete fragment where I can search for place in the map and I also put multiple markers in the map, what I wanted to do is to search those markers using the search bar, hope this clears up my question. Thankyouuu!!